# no graphics hardware acceleration (glx) in 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia-prime

I've just intalled ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop:

```
> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

My laptop has two graphic cards:

```
> lspci -k | grep -iA3 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF116M [GeForce GT 555M/635M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GeForce GT 555M
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

therefore, it is eligible to prime/optimus feature:

```
> prime-supported 
yes
```

I set the default graphics controller to be the nvidia one:

```
> prime-select nvidia
Info: the nvidia profile is already set
```

... las, after reboot, the system runs fine, but there is no graphics hardware acceleration: browser games run terribly slow. This is confirmed by:

```
> glxinfo 
name of display: :1
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

Answer (score 2):

solution: using

```
apt list *nvidia* | grep install
```

... I could compare my previous 19.10 system with the 20.04 one, and discovered that **nvidia-dkms-390** package was missing (why ?).

So, installing it solved the problem:

```
apt install nvidia-dkms-390
```